# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class AutoFitTextureView

Tags: java, android, camera, binary, layout-inflater

I get a crash on some devices because of Inflate exception, I'm trying to inflate a custom class called AutoFitTextureView, I get this Logcat message:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class com.xscoder.pikky.AutoFitTextureView
```

I'm using the Camera2 Basic code from google to open a custom camera.

Here's part of my **square_camera.xml** layout:

```
<com.xscoder.pikky.AutoFitTextureView
    android:id="@+id/texture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sqcTopView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#333"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</com.xscoder.pikky.AutoFitTextureView>
```

Here's the code of my **AutoFixTextureView** class:

```
public class AutoFitTextureView extends TextureView {


    private int mRatioWidth = 0;
    private int mRatioHeight = 0;

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }



    public void setAspectRatio(int width, int height) {
        if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be negative.");
        }
        mRatioWidth = width;
        mRatioHeight = height;
        requestLayout();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (0 == mRatioWidth || 0 == mRatioHeight) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight) {
                setMeasuredDimension(width, width * mRatioHeight / mRatioWidth);
            } else {
                setMeasuredDimension(height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight, height);
            }
        }
    }


}// ./ end
```

And here's where I call it:

```
public class SquareCamera extends AppCompatActivity {

private AutoFitTextureView mTextureView;
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.square_camera);

        mTextureView = findViewById(R.id.texture);
```

I really can't figure out what's wrong, because if I run my app on a real Huawei Cam 21 with Android 6.0 or a Quilive with Android 5.1, the app doesn't crash at all, but on other devices, and also an Android 8.0 emulator, it crashes with that error.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the bug by simply editing my **square_camera.xml** file as it follows:

```
<com.xscoder.pikky.AutoFitTextureView
    android:id="@+id/texture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sqcTopView"
   >
</com.xscoder.pikky.AutoFitTextureView>
```

It seems that some Android devices do no process additional attributes for a custom TextureView, so it's better to set the programmatically in Java :)